# Can't assign an array to a variable in an .ENV file (rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, environment-variables, environment

I want to create an array and assign it to a variable in a .env file, like so:

```
FOOD=["cookies", "grapes", "cake", "pie"]
```

And then, in a separate seed.rb file, create an instance of an object, like in the example below, and use the "FOOD" array to define an attribute of my object:

```
User.create(name: "jane doe", favorite_foods: ENV["FOOD"])
```

This doesn't work. When I seed the database, this instance of User is not created. Help please. I've seen stuff about "php" and "config" files, but nothing explicitly details step-by-step how to achieve this.

I put stuff in my .env that I don't want made visible when I push my app to Github or Heroku. So keep in mind that I don't want the FOOD array visible to any public spaces that will deploy/store my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using Foreman or Dotenv to load environment variables from a .env file. Follow the Rails installation instructions at https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv.

Here's the catch: as far as I can tell, you can't store an array as an environment variable directly. What you can do instead -- and this is what I do in most of my apps -- is use a comma-separated string, and process it in Ruby.

For example:

```
# .env
FOOD=cookies,grapes,cake,pie

# seeds.rb
User.create!(
  name: "Jane Doe",
  favorite_foods: ENV.fetch('FOOD').split(',')
)
```

This will split the comma-separated string into an array, and use that in assignment.

Using the `.create!` method (with the `!`) may help you debug why your instance isn't being created, as it will immediately return validation errors, etc.

Also, using `#fetch` here will ensure that environment variable is present, and will throw an error if not.

If you wanted the app to fall back to a default list if that environment variable was missing, you could also use:

```
ENV.fetch('FOOD', 'default,food,list').split(',')
#=> ['default', 'food', 'list']
```

Comment: this worked! thanks matt! i was already using the "dotenv" gem, but i had an array in there. this method of making it a comma-separated string, and then splitting it into an array in my seed.rb file worked!!

Comment: I have a question . can storage.yml from active stroage see enviroment varialbes in .env ?

Answer (score -1):

You need the **dotenv** gem installed to be able to load the .env environment variables.

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv